# Terraform two PostgreSQL databases setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, terraform

I am very very new to teraform scripting.
Our system is running in AWS and we have a single database server instance accessed   by multiple micro services.

Each micro service that needs to persist some data needs to point to a different database (schema) on the same database server. We prefer each service to have its own schema to have the services totally decoupled from each other. However creating a separate database instance to achieve this would be a bit too much as some services only persist close to nothing so it would be a waste,

I created the PostgreSQL resource in a **services.tf** script that is common to all microservices:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "my-system" {
  identifier_prefix       = "${var.resource_name_prefix}-tlm-"
  engine                  = "postgres"
  allocated_storage       = "${var.database_storage_size}"
  storage_type            = "${var.database_storage_type}"
  storage_encrypted       = true
  skip_final_snapshot     = true
  instance_class          = "${var.database_instance_type}"
  availability_zone       = "${data.aws_availability_zones.all.names[0]}"
  db_subnet_group_name    = "${aws_db_subnet_group.default.name}"
  vpc_security_group_ids  = "${var.security_group_ids}"
  backup_retention_period = "${var.database_retention_period}"
  backup_window           = "15:00-18:00"     // UTC
  maintenance_window      = "sat:19:00-sat:20:00" // UTC

  tags = "${var.tags}"
}
```

And now I for my service-1 and service-2 i want to be able to create the corespondent database name. I don't think the below is correct I am just adding it to give you an idea about what I am trying to achieve.

So **service-1.tf** will contain:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "my-system" {
  name                    = "service_1"
}
```

And **service-2.tf** will contain:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "my-system" {
  name                    = "service_2"
}
```

My question is what should I put in the service-1.tf and service-2.tf to make this possible.

Thank you in advance for your inputs.

Comment: Are you saying you want to have multiple postgres schemas and users separated by application on the same instance? How are you currently creating users and schemas on your RDS instance?

Comment: This is what I want to find out with my question. How can I automate with terraform  the creation of multiple schemas / users on the same database instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform can only manage at the RDS instance level. Configuring the schema etc is a DBA task.

One way you could automate the DBA tasks is by creating a **null_resource** using the **local-exec** provider to use a postgres client to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count-multiple-resource-instances) to manage one tf file only

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "my-system" {
  count                   = "2"
  name                    = "service_${count.index}"
  identifier_prefix       = "${var.resource_name_prefix}-tlm-"
  engine                  = "postgres"
  allocated_storage       = "${var.database_storage_size}"
  storage_type            = "${var.database_storage_type}"
  storage_encrypted       = true
  skip_final_snapshot     = true
  instance_class          = "${var.database_instance_type}"
  availability_zone       = "${data.aws_availability_zones.all.names[0]}"
  db_subnet_group_name    = "${aws_db_subnet_group.default.name}"
  vpc_security_group_ids  = "${var.security_group_ids}"
  backup_retention_period = "${var.database_retention_period}"
  backup_window           = "15:00-18:00"     // UTC
  maintenance_window      = "sat:19:00-sat:20:00" // UTC

  tags = "${var.tags}"
}
```

Comment: The question is confusing but they specifically say they only want one RDS instance, not 2.